# Project Euler 17 Answer wrong by a few digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Have coded everything and i think it works properly. the answer i should be getting is 21124, but i get 21116. The code is this, it is a bit long, and i'd also like some advice on how to make my code look smaller for future projects. The question is project Euler 17.

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?
>
> NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

```
num_word = {0: '', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight',
        9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen',
        15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty',
        30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty', 50: 'fifty', 60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty',
        90: 'ninety', 100: 'onehundred', 200: 'twohundred', 300: 'threehundred', 400: 'fourhundred',
        500: 'fivehundred', 600: 'sixhundred', 700: 'sevenhundred', 800: 'eighthundred',
        900: 'ninehundred', 1000: 'onethousand'
        }

word_list = ['one thousand']

for i in range(1, 1001):
    num_str = list(map(int, list(str(i))))
    if len(num_str) == 1:
        word_list.append(num_word[i])
    if len(num_str) == 2:
        if i in list(range(10, 21)):
            # digits from ten to twenty can be expressed in one word
            word_list.append(str(num_word[i]))
        if i in list(range(21, 101)):
            if num_str[1] == 0:
                word_list.append(num_word[i])
            # multiples of ten can be expressed in one word
            else:
                word_list.append(num_word[int(num_str[0]) * 10] + num_word[num_str[1]])
    #         two digit nos. from 20, that aren't multiples of ten need two vales: example: 41 = forty one

    if len(num_str) == 3:
        if num_word[num_str[2]] == 0:
            num_2_word = str(num_word[int(num_str[0]) * 100] + "and" + num_word[int(num_str[1]) * 10])
            word_list.append(num_2_word)
        if num_word[num_str[1]] == 1:
                x = int(num_str[1] + num_str[2])
                num_2_word = str(num_word[int(num_str[0]) * 100] + "and" + num_word[x])
                word_list.append(num_2_word)
        else:
                num_2_word = str(num_word[int(num_str[0]) * 100] + "and" + num_word[int(num_str[1]) * 10] + num_word[int(num_str[2])])
                word_list.append(num_2_word)

letter_count = 0

for num in word_list:
    str_num = list(str(num))
    for letter in str_num:
        letter_count += 1

print(letter_count)
```

Comment: Just using some print statments your code has a few issues, it we print out everything that is being appended to the list, you can see that while your answer is close its totally wrong. for the numbers `100, 111, 114` prints as `onehundredand, onehundredandtenone, onehundredandtenfour` so while your number is close it is only close by chance and you need to sort your bugs first

Answer (score 1):

As i said in my comment, you have a few bugs in your code that mean while your number is close, its just coincidence. printing out your numbers yields a few issues like with the numbers 100, 114 etc. In regards to your second comment making your code smaller the question interested me to see how i would write it. Now i am sure there will be more succient and neat answers below is what i wrote to solve this problem. It essentially focuses on starting our words string with "onethousand" then handling the numbers 1 to 999. We convert the number to a string and pad it with leading 0s so all our strings are 3 chars long. 1 becomes 001 etc. We then just say if the value of that unit is not 0 then do something.

```py
num_words = {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six", "7": "seven", "8": "eight",
             "9": "nine", "10": "ten", "11": "eleven", "12": "twelve", "13": "thirteen", "14": "fourteen", "15": "fifteen",
             "16": "sixteen", "17": "seventeen", "18": "eighteen", "19": "nineteen", "20": "twenty", "30": "thirty",
             "40": "forty", "50": "fifty", "60": "sixty", "70": "seventy", "80": "eighty", "90": "ninety"}

words = "onethousand"

for i in range(1, 1000):
    num = f"{i:03}"
    num_word = ""
    if num[0] != "0":
        num_word += num_words[num[0]] + "hundred"
        if int(num[1:]) != 0:
            num_word += "and"
    if num[1] != "0":
        if num[1:] in num_words:
            num_word += num_words[num[1:]]
        else:
            num_word += num_words[num[1]+"0"]
    if num[2] != "0":
        if num[1:] not in num_words:
            num_word += num_words[num[2]]
    words+=num_word
print(len(words))
```

this gives the output 21124

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rethink your algorithm. And try to structure it differently by defining proper cases.

In your code, we can see that you made a special case for 2 numbers length and 3 numbers length... In reality you should try to follow the common language rules as much as possible.

So you'll have to extract some values...

Let start with those rules:

- numbers between 11 and 19 are "teen" numbers
- numbers between 1 and 9 are simple numbers and are expressed as is
- multiple of 10 are ten,twenty...ninety
- multiple of 100 are simple number + hundred
- multiple of 1000 are above rules + thounsand
- Then it's easy from 1 to 999 thousand you use the same rule as above and for each thousand, million and so on.

So what you have to do is extract the thousands like such a thousand can be any number between 1,000 to 999,999.

To extract the thousands, you have to do something like this:

```
num // 1000 % 1000
```

This will give you the amount of thousands... Then you just have to parse it as a number between 1 and 999 as usual.

Then you have to extract the remaining 999 below 1 thousand

You can do it as such:

```
num % 1000
```

Then now you have to parse those numbers from 1 to 999

You'll want to first extract the hundreads with num // 100 so if you and more than 0 it means you can parse the simple number (1-9) + hundred.

Then you have to parse the remaining 99 with num % 100

if number is between 1 and 9, it's a simple number

if it's between 10 and 19 it's a teen number

If it's above or equal 20 then you have to extract the multiple of 10 and the simple number.

You can do it with num // 10 and num % 10.
Then all you have to do is find the multiple of 10 for num // 10 and the simple number for num % 10.

If you find a 0 you don't parse it.

So parsing a number like 234234 should yield something like

```
two hundred thirty-four thousand two hundred thirty four
```

You can see that the number repeat itself.. separated by thousand, millions etc. What it means for you is that if you want to put the euler challenge a bit further, you can memoize your function in order to process numbers from 1 to 99 then hundreads from 1 to 9 + 1-99. Instead of doing 999 operation you'll do around 9 + 10 + 80 + 9 to process everything. So if you compute 99 once you can reuse the value for 199,299,399 etc... To put the test further, as it's only asking for the numbers of letter you can make the test further by knowing that if you have

9 times 99 letters you can multiple the amount of each by the amount of letters from the hundreds and sum the results without computing anything. Which means you don't even have to compute all numbers..

you just have to sum 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 in letters and multiply by the 99 in numbers and you'll be able to reduce a lot of calculation required.